# Magento 1.9.0.1 - FedEx rate quote module stopped working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, fedex

Some time between Friday and today, Aug 11, customers cannot proceed past the first step in the checkout process IF the FedEx shipping module is enabled in Magento 1.9.0.1.

Is anyone aware of something FedEx has done int he last three days that could be causing this?

If I disable FedEx shipping then the problem goes away.

No changes have been made to the Magento install since it WAS working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got through to FedEx. It is a problem on Their end that has been ongoing all day apparently.